# From generalized eigenvector to Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

I can't figure out the following part of Chen's *Linear Systems* book. How does he "readily obtain" $Av_2=v_1+\lambda v_2$?

---

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the fact that we have a "chain of generalized eigenvectors" implies that $(A - \lambda I)v_i = v_{i-1}$. So, we have
$$
(A - \lambda I)v_2 = v_1 \implies Av_2 - \lambda v_2 = v_1 \implies Av_2 = v_1 + \lambda v_2.
$$